# Ising model at high vs. low temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models

The output of the Ising model over a 2D binary lattice looks to have spin states uniformly distributed over the lattice for high values of the temperature parameter with the output attaining increasing structure as the temperature is lowered.  Have any formal, concrete relationships been found relating the temperature parameter with the distance of the lattice from one where spin states are uniformly distributed?

Comment: What is a "binary lattice"?

Comment: Presumably a lattice at which the "spins" can be either "up" or "down", i.e., two possible choices for spin,

Comment: It is not clear at all to me what the question really is. _A lot_ is know about properties of these Gibbs measures, so it will probably be possible to answer your question once you have clarified it. (Note, in particular, that the spins form an iid Bernoulli field only at infinite temperature, and that the measure you get at any two distinct temperatures are mutually singular, so you should make the notion of distance you want more precise).